# How to use window.onload when HTML rendered in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

My API returns me the HTML. It has an option to switch between multiple languages and the content for all languages is already embedded in the single HTML.

There is an onload function inside the HTML that sets the default language.

```
function toggleLanguage(language) {
        // Hide all content
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-language]').forEach(function(el) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        });

        // Show content for the selected language
        document.querySelectorAll('[data-language="' + language + '"]').forEach(function(el) {
            el.style.display = 'block';
        });
}

window.onload = function() {
    toggleLanguage('english');
};

<div class="abcd" data-language="english">Additional Charges & Terms</div>
<div class="abcd" data-language="spanish">Cargos y condiciones adicionales</div>
```

I'm using `v-html` inside my Vue file to render the content received from API

```
<div v-html="factsLabelTemplate"></div>
```

My issue here is window.onload is not getting triggered and I'm seeing the content in all languages.

Comment: "My issue here is window.onload is not getting triggered" ... have you verified this? console.log something in the handler to see if it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `mounted` [lifecycle hook](https://www.w3schools.com/vue/ref_lh_mounted.php). Here is how you can use that:

**Your HTML:**

```html
<div v-html="factsLabelTemplate"></div>
```

**Script:**

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      factsLabelTemplate: ''
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('your-api-endpoint')
      .then(response => {
        this.factsLabelTemplate= response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching HTML content:', error);
      });
    
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I will make the API call to retrieve HTML and show it in an Dialog up on click of a particular button on the page. I have also tried making the call in mounted and it looks the same. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

you can  make the call  in  nextTick api

```
import { nextTick} from 'vue'
// after api call
factsLabelTemplate.value = response.data
nextTick(()=>{
    toggleLanguage('english');
})
```

Comment: I see below error as `toogleLanguage` is part of the rendered HTML and not in my Vue code.
error  'toggleLanguage' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: If the response is a complete webpage  that contains html ,body ,script,and so on, you can create a iframe element to load it.